# what issues are there with upgrading Zend Framework to 1.9.1 from 1.7.6

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm working on a project that is currently using the Zend Framework 1.7.6, however the current release of the framework 1.9.1 has some features that would really make my life a little easier, so I want to update the framework.

As this is quite a jump I know that it is going to break parts of my application.  Items such as the bootstrap are very different between the versions. Apart from this what other issues can you see me hitting if I do this update?  What experience has anyone had updating to 1.9.1 from a lower version??

I'm just trying to justify, what I think might be a little painful to complete.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most important change is *new Autoloader* with optimistic namespace matching. But you can use fallbackAutoloader feature (see manual) to revert to old-style autoloading.

Other change is _Zend_Application_ and new *Bootstraping process* - but I guess there is no need to use it. You can still use your old bootstrap. Just couple fixes here and there ;)

So much for the most important changes from my point of view.

Comment: cheers for this, just tried it on a branch of the app and initial playing around and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `Zend_Validate_NotEmpty`, and were doing anything strange like filtering input to be an object of some sort, `Zend_Validate_NotEmpty` now causes an error if the item isn't a float/int/string/array/boolean - so Objects don't cut the grade anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the autoloader, you should also have to check the signatures of any methods you have overridden as a fair few have changed.